# laravel 5.2 get image from storage folder

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-5

I need to view the image in browser with image tag. I have used laravel storage folder to store the images and I want to display it in browse with img src and i am getting blank response. following is the code please tell me where do i mistake.

Laravel code

route.php

```
Route::get('uploads/{folder?}/{subFolder?}/{fileName?}', ['as' => 'file_preview', 'uses' => 'StorageController@preview']);
```

StorageController.php

```
public function preview($folder, $subFolder, $fileName)
{
    $tFile = \File::get(storage_path('uploads/'.$folder.'/'.$subFolder.'/'.$fileName));

    return Response::make($tFile)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpg'); 
}
```

HTML code for view image

```
<img src="{!! route('file_preview', ['folder'=> 'category','subFolder' => 'style','fileName'=>$category->style_img]) !!}" width="130" height="130" id="default_image" class="editCategoryPreviewStyleImage" />
```

Please tell me the best approach to get this.